# How to remove all inline styles and other attributes from html elements using Jsoup?

Tags: java, android, jsoup, html-parsing

How to remove all inline styles and other attributes(class,onclick) from html elements using Jsoup?

Sample Input :

```
<div style="padding-top:25px;" onclick="javascript:alert('hi');">
This is a sample div <span class='sampleclass'> This is a sample span </span>
</div>
```

Sample Output :

```
<div>This is a sample div <span> This is a sample span </span> </div>
```

My Code (Is this is a right way or any other better approach is there?)

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements el = doc.getAllElements();
for (Element e : el) {
    Attributes at = e.attributes();
    for (Attribute a : at) {    
        e.removeAttr(a.getKey());    
    }
}
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for the reply. See my updated question. Is this is a right way or any other better approach is there ??

Comment: @vjy Is that updated code working for you? Or still not working?

Comment: @ashatte I found the working code and updated in the question. I want to know what I am doing is right or any other better api, instead of iterating through all elements to clear attributes ??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, one method is indeed to iterate through the elements and call `removeAttr();`

An alternative method using jsoup is to make use of the `Whitelist` class (see [docs](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Whitelist.html)), which can be used with the `Jsoup.clean()` function to remove any non-specified tags or attributes from the document.

For example:

```
String html = "<html><head></head><body><div style='padding-top:25px;' onclick='javascript.alert('hi');'>This is a sample div <span class='sampleclass'>This is a simple span</span></div></body></html>";

Whitelist wl = Whitelist.simpleText();
wl.addTags("div", "span"); // add additional tags here as necessary
String clean = Jsoup.clean(html, wl);
System.out.println(clean);
```

Will result in the following output:

```
11-05 19:56:39.302: I/System.out(414): <div>
11-05 19:56:39.302: I/System.out(414):  This is a sample div 
11-05 19:56:39.302: I/System.out(414):  <span>This is a simple span</span>
11-05 19:56:39.302: I/System.out(414): </div>
```